# Why application with version 2 envelope working on OS X 10.9 not accepted by gatekeeper on OS X 10.10?

Tags: macos, code-signing, osx-yosemite, osx-gatekeeper

We have a Mono Mac app which is distributed outside of AppStore signed by Developer Id certificate. Gatekeeper accepts the app on OS X 10.9 (tested on 10.9.4), but it fails to accept on 10.10 DP 7.

**The output of some troubleshooting commands on 10.10 DP 7:**

```
mactesters-Mac-mini:myapp 1 mactester$ spctl --assess -v ./myapp.app
./myapp.app: rejected
source=obsolete resource envelope

mactesters-Mac-mini:myapp 1 mactester$ codesign -v myapp.app
myapp.app: resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)

mactesters-Mac-mini:myapp 1 mactester$ codesign -dv myapp.app/
Executable=/Volumes/myapp 1/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp.sh
Identifier=com.Company.myapp
Format=bundle with generic
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=145 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1+3 location=embedded
Signature size=8531
Timestamp=03 Sep 2014 16:55:21
Info.plist entries=32
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=5 files=813
Internal requirements count=2 size=224
mactesters-Mac-mini:myapp 1 mactester$
```

**The output for the same application on 10.9:**

```
macadmins-iMac:myapp mactester$ spctl --assess -v ./myapp.app
./myapp.app: accepted
source=Developer ID

macadmins-iMac:myapp mactester$ codesign --verify --deep --verbose=4 ./myapp.app
./myapp.app: valid on disk
./myapp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

macadmins-iMac:myapp mactester$ codesign -dv myapp.app
Executable=/Volumes/myapp/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp.sh
Identifier=com.Company.myapp
Format=bundle with generic
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=145 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1+3 location=embedded
Signature size=8531
Timestamp=03 Sep 2014 16:54:50
Info.plist entries=32
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=5 files=813
Internal requirements count=2 size=224
```

**The code signing commands used are not containing the --resource-rules flag:**

```
codesign -v --force --sign 'dev id...' /Volumes/myapp/myapp.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
codesign -v --force --sign 'dev id...' /Volumes/myapp/myapp.app
```

What does custom omit rules mean? How this problem can be resolved?

Comment: Did you get this problem fixed?  I just stumbled upon it today and am having trouble finding resources on this

Comment: Just a guess:  The problem might be the dylib in a nonstandard location.  [Tech Note 2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) lists the standard places for nested code.

Comment: @JWWalker Thanx for the hint. I'll update the post once we have investigated this.

Answer (score 1):

The "custom omit rules" error is due to using the --resource-rules flag during signing. This flag has been deprecated for some time and it's no longer accepted by Gatekeeper as of OSX 10.9.5. You can safely remove it, though, version 2 signatures are backwards compatible and can even work with OSX 10.6 (I have tested that).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I can't add a comment to their post due to my low reputation.

Comment: @lrakis Thanks for the contribution but this is SO policy, and that's why there is a Comment privilege.

Comment: @evanwong Thanks for the heads-up, I turned this into an actual answer and provided some more info, I hope it's ok now.

Comment: @evanwong: In my opinion, the original version of this answer was OK as an answer.  The fact that it contained a question mark indicated that it involved a bit of guesswork, not that it was primarily a question.

Comment: I have added the code signing commands to the post. --resource-rules was not used